# capital or small letter in the first letter after a term definition double colons

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

If I am using double colons to define a term, shall I start the first letter after it with capital or small?

Example:

> Top-websites: Websites that are visited by more than # users each day.

Or,

> Top-websites: websites that are visited by more than # users each day.

Comment: Are you following some style guide? If not, this is a matter of opinion, but be consistent either way.

Comment: This is a question of style, and it depends on which guide you choose to follow.

Comment: *The Chicago Manual of Style* currently gives guidance to use a lowercase letter—unless what follows the colon is a question, in which case an uppercase letter should be used. But that's just one style guide. However, I believe *all* style guides would say that if what follows is a proper noun (it isn't in your example), then it should be in uppercase regardless of anything else.